# Static member array of pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, static

I am trying to define in a .cpp file an attribute which should be an array of pointers to member functions of a class named Hand.

Both the array and the functions are members of Hand and the array is static(please correct me if it should not).

This is what I reached:

```
static bool Hand::*(Hand::hfunctions)[] ()=
{&Hand::has_sflush,&Hand::has_poker,&Hand::has_full,&Hand::has_flush,
&Hand::has_straight,&Hand::has_trio,&Hand::has_2pair,&Hand::has_pair};
```

I get this error: hand.cpp:96:42: error: declaration of ‘hfunctions’ as array of functions.

I guess the type definition is worng so I need to know how can I make the definition right

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is a rather convoluted one:

```
class Hand
{
    bool has_sflush();
    static bool (Hand::*hfunctions[])();
    ...
};

bool (Hand::*Hand::hfunctions[])() = {&Hand::has_sflush, ...};
```

A way to get to this is by gradually increasing complexity, using [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) to check yourself at each step:

```
int (*hFunctions)()
```

> declare hFunctions as pointer to function returning int

---

```
int (Hand::*hFunctions)()
```

> declare hFunctions as pointer to member of class Hand function returning int
>
> Warning: Unsupported in C -- 'pointer to member of class'

---

```
int (Hand::*hFunctions[])()
```

> declare hFunctions as array of pointer to member of class Hand function returning int
>
> Warning: Unsupported in C -- 'pointer to member of class'

---

Now replace `int` by `bool` (sadly, cdecl.org doesn't understand `bool`); so you get the syntax of the declaration.

For the definition, replace `hFunctions` by Hand::hFunctions, and add the initialization part, like you did.

Comment: cdecl.org, I didn't know that tool, thanks!! If it worked for c++ would be even better

Answer (score 2):

> Both the array and the functions are members of Hand and the array is static(please correct me if it should not).

If I understand correctly what you are asking, **you should not**. You should abstract the operation as a base class, specialize it and hold the array as an array of pointers to the base class:

```
struct Match // need a better name
{
     virtual bool matches() = 0;
     virtual ~Match() = default;
};

struct MatchSFlush: public Match { ... };

class Hand
{
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Match>> matches;
};
```

Comment: "you should not" - i guess this means "you should not implement this the way you did"; the question was "should the array be static?". Anyway +1.

Comment: Yes, it was about not implementing it this way. Usually when you need to create an array of functions to abstract behavior, that means "go virtual".

Comment: I will have to research in order to understand this answer. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: My point was that your has_sflush, has_poker (and so on) functions should not be a set of member functions in Hand, but a hierarchy of classes outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **non static** member functions with no arguments and returning `bool` you should write something like

```
typedef bool (Hand::*hfunction_non_static)();
hfunction_non_static f_non_static [] =
{
    &Hand::has_sflush,
    &Hand::has_poker,
    .......
}; 
Hand h;
(h.*f_non_static[0])();
```

If you have **static** functions you should write something like

```
typedef bool (*hfunction_static)();
hfunction_static f_static [] = {&Hand::has_sflush, ....};
f_static[0]();
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not exactly what I was asking because I had trouble when I had to tell the compiler that "hfunctions is member of Hand" in the .cpp file. Anyway I have learned a lot from your answer, for instance that the usage of typedef makes this easier.